# Condition "and", "or"

Tags: python

I have a problem with my condition. I would like the variable `tabPoint` to be between 10 and 100.

Here is my code:

```
def demand(nb):
  tabName = [];
  tabPoint = [];

  for i in range(nb):
    tabName.append(raw_input("Name of the jumper " + str(i+1) +  " : "))
    tabPoint.append(input("1st jump  " + tabName [i] + " The number must be between 10 and 100: " ));

    if int (tabPoint[i] < 5 ) and int (tabPoint[i] > 100):
       tabPoint.append(input("The number must be between 10 and 100 " ));

  return tabName, tabPoint; 

name, point = demand(3)
print(name, point)
```

Comment: 1) your parentheses are in the wrong place. 2) less than 5 and *greater than 100*? How is that possible?

Comment: you also don't need `;` at line endings

Comment: You want it to be less than 5 *and* greater than 100? That's impossible. Do you mean *or*?

Comment: Sorry, in fact the condition must be between 10 and 100

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced your parentheses. What you want as an int is `tabPoint[i]`, *not* `tabPoint[i] < 5`.

So the correct form is

```
if int(tabPoint[i]) > 5 and int(tabPoint[i]) < 100:
   tabPoint.append(input("The number must be between 10 and 100 " ))
```

You can also use the short version that accomplishes the same:

```
if 5 < int(tabPoint[i]) < 100:
    tabPoint.append(input("The number must be between 10 and 100 "))
```

Comment: that logic makes no sense, if <5 and >100 how is that between 10 and 100?

Comment: 5-100 != 10-100, even though the OP mentions it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def demand(nb):
    tabName = []
    tabPoint = []

    for i in range(nb):
        tabName.append(input("Name of the jumper "+str(i+1)+": "))
        tabPoint.append(0)

        # Until a valid entry is made, this prompt will occur
        while tabPoint[i] < 10 or tabPoint[i] > 100:
            tabPoint[i] = (int(
                input("1st jump "+tabName[i]+" The number must be between 10 "
                      "and 100: ")))


    return dict(zip(tabName, tabPoint))  # Returning a dictionary mapping name to point
```

Say you wanted to print each name and point after this, you could implement something like:

```
info = demand(3)

for name, point in info.items():
    print(f"Name: {name} Point: {point}")
```